# Creating transition effects in XNA

Tags: xna, transition, effects

I'm a beginner at the MS XNA Framework (v.4). I am trying to build a small game and wanted to know how to add transition effects to it (for example I want when a score appears it gets bigger then fades).

Could anybody point me in the right direction? I tried googling it but I didn't find any useful links.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

Transitions are usually in the Update method of your object.

For instance, if you have a ScoreDisplay object named scoredisp, when you call the method, let's say, `GetBigger()`, every following calls of the `scoredisp.Update(gameTime)` should increase the scale variable of the object, and then it should be drawn depending of the scale variable. You can use a bool variable to determine if the transition is currently being applied to the object

Ex:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{

    If(isGrowthActivated)
    {
        scale += 1.50f * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }
    //Any other scoreDisplay update code...
}

public void GetBigger()
{
    isGrowthActivated = true;
}
```

Don't forget to call `scoredisp.Update(gameTime);` in the Update method of your game though.

The amount of transitions you can create is limitless, but all roughly follow the same pattern.

(You should always have transitions depending on the elapsedGameTime of the frame, so it runs the same at different fps)

Hope this helps!